# Comment "baf" était une onomatopée? Comment évoquer ce qui est épais, enflé, goulu ?

Tags: onomatopées

[bâfrer — Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A2frer)

> *(XVIe siècle)* Peut-être du moyen français *[bauffrer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=bauffrer&action=edit&redlink=1)*. Dérivé de l’onomatopée *baf* évoquant ce qui est épais, enflé, goulu.
>
> Peut-être des langues germaniques *[baf](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/baf#gem)* (« lèvre »).

1. How was *baf* an onomatopoeia? Did Middle French people utter *baf* whilst eating?
2. How does *baf* evoke "ce qui est épais, enflé, goulu"?

Comment: In French we would ask : "Baf était-il bien une onomatopée ?" "Est-ce que "baf" était vraiment une onomatopée?" or even "Comment baf a-t-il pu être une onomatopée?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the etymology of "baffe", from the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baffe).

> ÉTYMOL. ET HIST. − [L'éd. Am. Salmon de Ph. de Beaumanoir, Coutumes Beauvaisis indique bufe sans var. (§ 916) au passage cité d'après l'éd. Beugnot ds Gdf. et T.-L., s.v. bafe]; 1435, 28 janv. Reg. aux sentences, Arch. Douai ds Gdf. : lui donna une baffe; repris en 1750 arg. baffe (Vadé, Lettres de La Grenouillère, p. 35 : Elle m'a encore apliqué une baffe d'sus l'visage), attesté aussi sous la forme baffre (A. Delvau, Dict. de la lang. verte, 1867). Formé de l'onomat. baf, exprimant la notion de « gonflé, boursouflé », d'où la notion de « coup »; cf. m. fr. bauffree « soufflet » 1466 ds Gdf. À rapprocher de l'a. fr. buffe « coup de poing, tape » (xiiies. ds T.-L.) et du lat. médiév. buffa « id. » 1273 (Charta Philippi Reg. pro Ecclesia S. Mederici Parisiens. ds Du Cange, t. 1, p. 769c), issus de l'onomat. buff- exprimant le souffle, le gonflement.

*Notions extracted from the above etymology*

- 1435 *baffe* (slap) → 1750 slang *baffe* (slap) also *baffre* ("langue verte" i.e. quasi slang)
  out of onomatopoeia "*baf*" meant to express swollenness, therefrom the notion of *blow*; cf middle French *bauffree* (slap) 1466.  assimilated to *buffe* (punch, hit); from Medieval Latin "*buffa*" 1273 used to express "breath", "swollenness", this latter issued from the onomatopoeia "buff" (breath, swollenness).

Here is the etymology of "bâfrer" ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2frer)).

> ÉTYMOL. ET HIST. − 1507 baufrer « manger goulûment » (E. d'Amerval, Livre de la Diablerie, éd. Charles-Fréd. Ward, Iowa, [1923], 62a : Tous bons francoys gloutons gourmans ... Qui baufrent tant bien que merveilles) graphie attestée jusqu'en 1718, Ac.; 1740 bâfrer (Ac.), qualifié de 'bas et fam.' ibid. Formé de l'onomatopée baf, baff, exprimant qqc. d'épais, de boursouflé, de gonflé (FEW s.v., t. 1, p. 203a) d'où manger gloutonnement, ce qui fait enfler les joues; à rapprocher des formations expressives pop. bouffer, brifer, etc.

Here is the etymology of "bâfrer" from  [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/b%C3%A2frer).

> ÉTYMOLOGIE
> Berry, baufrer ; piémont. bafrè. Diez le rattache à bave, citant le picard bafe, gourmand, et baflier, baveur ; dérivation qui reste douteuse. On trouve dans l'ancien français baufrée, avec le sens de pièce et avec celui de soufflet ; ce qui porte à croire que bafre ou baufre signifie les joues et, par extension, joue pendante, pièce ; d'où viendrait bâfrer avec le sens qu'il a : de la sorte il se rattacherait au radical baf ou bav, lèvres (voy. BAFOUER). Il y a aussi dans le dictionnaire de Thomas, publié par Maï, t. VIII, p. 71 : bafer, grossus, turgidus, ventriculosus ; d'où l'on tirerait sans peine le verbe baferare, s'emplir la panse. Mais rien n'est certain.

More likely, the onomatopoeia results *from the word naming "slap" and the sound that results from it* (there being a coincidence of sounds), and not from a use of the word as a statement of fact when they had eaten in plenty and felt their stomach was swollen by the food, but who knows. There is no indubitable evidence but the following group of onomatopoeia tends to show that (although some of them are of recent origin).

> ([Les Onomatopées](http://www.les-onomatopees.fr/liste-onomatopees.php)) Claque - Baf! Paf!, Sbaf!, Spank!, Sblaf!, Paf!

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatop%C3%A9e)) Baff (bruit semblable à celui d'une gifle)

It seems then that the Medieval Latin "*buffa*" for "breath" and the associated "swollen breast" is at the origin of "baf" as the onomatopoeia meaning "swollen"; the additional idea concerning gluttony (goulu) could result from the swollen shapes that engenders gluttonous behaviour (cheeks and stomach while eating, corpulence all the time).